# Get point on sphere's surface from a random point

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, geometry

I am creating a game with Unity and I have a math problem.
I have a sphere with a radius of 10 and center of (0, 0, 0).
I want the camera to move around that sphere, but I can't find anywhere a way to do what I want to.
I move the camera in the X axis and the Y axis (and therefore get a point outside of the sphere) and I want to set it's Z axis so the camera would be back on the sphere, I am using this equation: r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 => z^2 = r^2 - x^2 - y^2
But it doesn't work… Please help me

**EDIT**

This is my code (in c#):

```
    private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var newX = mainCameraTransform.position.x + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    var newY = mainCameraTransform.position.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    var maxDistance = 10.0f;
    newX = Mathf.Clamp(newX, -maxDistance * 0.85f, maxDistance * 0.85f);
    newY = Mathf.Clamp(newY, 1.0f * 0.85f, maxDistance * 0.85f);
    var newZ = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(maxDistance * maxDistance - newX * newX - newY * newY));

    mainCameraTransform.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);
    mainCameraTransform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);
}
```

As you can see I used Clamp to keep the X and Y less then the radius but it didn't help…

Comment: As long as x²+y²<r², it does work (and is the only way if you want to keep x and y).

Comment: Do you want to generate 3d random point on sphere surface?

Comment: Are you simply trying to constrain the camera to the sphere? Might it be easier to use a rotation instead of setting x and y? Without more details, it's a bit difficult to guess where things are going wrong. Can you post code?

Comment: All I want to do is to create 3D view, the camera suppose to look at the model at any time, and I change the point of view by dragging the mouse. for that I move the camera according to the drag direction and with built in code I rotate it to the center.

The only thing I don't know is how to keep the camera in the sphere (or in it's surface at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but it should be pretty close

```
private void OnMouseDrag(){
    Vector3 newPos =  mainCameraTransform.position;
    newPos += mainCameraTransform.up * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    newPos += mainCameraTransform.right * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    newPos = newPos.normalized * 10f;
    mainCameraTransform.position = newPos;
    mainCameraTransform.LookAt(Vector3.zero, mainCameraTransform.up);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit 2D coordinates by circle border

```
len = Mathf.Sqrt(newX * newX + newY * newY);
//perhaps you have Len or Hypot function in your Math library

if len > maxDistance then
     newX = maxDistance * newX / len
     newY = maxDistance * newY / len;
```

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop this script on the camera to orbit it around a target using the right mouse button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrbitAroundObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 10.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

    public float yMinLimit = -20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    public float smoothTime = 2f;

    public float zoomSpeed = 1;

    float rotationYAxis = 0.0f;
    float rotationXAxis = 0.0f;

    float velocityX = 0.0f;
    float velocityY = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        rotationYAxis = angles.y;
        rotationXAxis = angles.x;

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>()) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        if (target) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
                velocityX += xSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 0.02f;
                velocityY += ySpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 0.02f;
            }

            //distance -= (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y*Time.deltaTime);
            distance = Mathf.Lerp(distance, distance-(Input.mouseScrollDelta.y*zoomSpeed) , Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            rotationYAxis += velocityX;
            rotationXAxis -= velocityY;

            rotationXAxis = ClampAngle(rotationXAxis, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            //Quaternion fromRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationXAxis, rotationYAxis, 0);
            Quaternion rotation = toRotation;


            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;

            velocityX = Mathf.Lerp(velocityX, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
            velocityY = Mathf.Lerp(velocityY, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
        }

    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max) {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```